# Load xml after getting file from folder in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a Javascript that has to run in WSH.
The objective is to read 2 xml files from local disk. The script has to fetch the 2 files from  2 different folders, which have been determined in a config.xml.

Example of the config.xml

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<file>
    <name>C:\Users\changeFolder\</name>
</file>
<file>
    <name>C:\Users\supplyFolder\</name>
</file>
```

In these 2 folder are files called change.xml ( in changeFolder ) and supply.xml ( in supplyFolder ).

What i do next is i get the value from the config xml and store in a var:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
    var folderNaam1 = getNodeValue(naamElementConfig[0]);
    var folderNaam2 = getNodeValue(naamElementConfig[1]);
```

I wrote my own function getNodeValue which looks like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
    function getNodeValue(target) {
        return target.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
```

This function returns the exact path described in the xml:

```
C:\Users\changeFolder\
C:\Users\supplyFolder\
```

My next function is one to get the first file out of these folders. It's no problem that i only take the first file cause their should never be 2 files in the folder.
The way i do this is with next function:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var fileNaam1 = getFileOutFolder(folderNaam1);
var fileNaam2 = getFileOutFolder(folderNaam2);
```

Using this function:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
function getFileOutFolder(folder) {
    var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folder);

    var colFiles = new Enumerator(objFolder.Files);

    return colFiles.item();
}
```

When i check the return value of this function i get what i expected to get:

```
C:\Users\changeFolder\change.xml
C:\Users\supplyFolder\supply.xml
```

When i enter this value in my loadXml function it doesn't work. This is the XMLLoad function i wrote:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
function loadXML(name) {
    var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    if(!xmlDoc.load(name)) {
        WScript.Echo("Error reason: " + xmlDoc.parseError.reason);
    }
    return xmlDoc;
}
```

The scripts gives an error at `if(!xmlDoc.load(name))`. The error is:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument.
```

So i suspect that the name variable (which is the complete path of my xml file i want to read in) is wrong.

The strange part is when i copy and paste the exact path in the xml config, read that path and us it as name parameter is does work fine. So i don't know where the script goes wrong when reading the file name.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the paths you give actual paths? Isn't there a username containing spaces in the path? Not sure what impact that may have if it's the case, though.

Comment: I made a shorter version of the paths, normally its /users/nameofuser/... . I just made it shorter to be easier to read

Answer (score 0):

Got a fix, not sure why this actually works but i added something in the getFileOutFolder function. Instead of returning colFiles.item() i now return **colFiles.item() + ""**. By adding the + "" the script is working. Not sure why, but maybe it could help others!